# How to implement tagging system in my JSP page for liferay 6.2 portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-aui, spring-portlet-mvc

I developed a portlet using liferay 6.2.
I need to have a tagging system in my JSP Page. 
For example,when i write the word "developer" inside an input I need that word will be like a tag.
When I followed the tutorial from the official Site, there are many error in the code and didn't understood what should I import exactly.
I need it to behave the same way as working in liferay like this
[image]

Hope that my question is clear and thanks for helping and tell me how implement it.I need it Soon.

Thanks.

Comment: check the Liferay tag being used for this functionality and use the same in your custome page!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @ShivamAggarwal - that makes the question easier to understand and I've retracted my "too broad" close vote. However, I shouldn't have, because I can't vote because of "debugging help needs code": It'd be good to know what problems exist in the existing tutorials, rather than stating "it doesn't work". OP: Please edit and provide more details what you already have and what works and what doesn't

Comment: Yes,please provide what errors do you face and what code snippet had you tried.

Comment: You could use token input. http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/